# program to perform in sentence each first letter of the word should be in Upper case using c#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Program
{
     public static void Main()
 {
  List<string> stringList = new List<string>{"abca","two","three","four","five","six"};
  stringList.ForEach(x=>{
   Console.WriteLine(x.Replace(x[0],Char.ToUpper(x[0])));
  });
 }
}
```

program to replace the first letter with capital letter in each sentences using c# console application but its providing the output like "AbcA".

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Do you need output for

one two three - line 1
four five six - line 2

AS
One two three - line 1
Four five six - line 2
OR
One Two Three - line 1
Four Five Six - line 2

Comment: Look at **ToTitleCase** on the **TextInfo** class (in System.Globalization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You program will not work for if the list contains "abca", the output will be "AbcA".

use instead this:

```
char.ToUpper(x[0]) + x.Substring(1);
```

I let you manage the case when x is empty or has only one character

Comment: I am replacing the first character of the string  x.Replace(x[0],Char.ToUpper(x[0])) . so it will work for the string contains "abca" then the output will be "Abca"

Comment: @Jagath No, you are instructing [`Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.replace#System_String_Replace_System_Char_System_Char_) to replace _all occurrences_ of the `char` at `x[0]` (`'a'`) with `Char.ToUpper(x[0])` (`'A'`).  Just because the `char` you specify to be replaced happens to be the first `char` of the `string` does not limit `Replace()`'s search to the first `char` of the `string`.  If you [run your snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/aouIXJ) you will see the result is `"AbcA"` not `"Abca"`.

Comment: @BACON thanks for your idea. I tried it gives like "AbcA" so I have changed like char.ToUpper(x[0]) + x.Substring(1) this and its working fine now.

Answer (score -3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
  List<string> stringList = new List<string>{"one","two","three","four","five","six"};
  stringList.ForEach(x=>{
   Console.WriteLine(char.ToUpper(x[0]) + x.Substring(1););
  });
 }
}
```

program to replace the first letter with capital letter in each sentences using c# console application.

```
Output :
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
```

Comment: Try with sample string `"abca"`, as the OP did - it will fail for the same reason

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I have tried it gives the wrong out put. then I have used above answer from "Hassen" char.ToUpper(x[0]) + x.Substring(1); its working fine for me.

Comment: Ah, you *are* the OP. While you *are* allowed to *answer* your own question, this should have been an edit to your original question. You can still do that and delete this "answer"